# Why does my DLookup only return the first record?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to use a DLookup in Access VBA, but even with a criteria (hard-coded or from a text box), the lookup only returns the value from the first record in the table, not a record that matches the criteria.

Here is my code;

```
JOBID = DLookup("[ID]", "[MASTER PLANNER]", "[JOB NUMBER] = '" & Me.JOB_NUMBER & "'")
```

ID is a numerical ID field, [JOB NUMBER] is a string (like this; S019191-1) and JOB_NUMBER is the field on the form.

Anyone have any ideas on this at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying your DLookup returns the JOBID from the first record in the [MASTER PLANNER] table and that record DOES NOT have a [JOB NUMBER] matching Me.JOB_NUMBER ?

Answer (score 1):

Dlookup function return value. Not record. 
If you want to return all the record/s you can do it with :
1. Query  - do display the results in form/report.
2. Recordset - to use it in vba code. 
 Here is an explain how to use recordsets: 
[How to use recordsets for beginners](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Recordsets_for_Beginners)